# Is there a way to have parameters file to add mock data for dev environment as email/password?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using this code to insert email and password in `debug` buildTypes:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    mEmailEditText.setText("devtest@....com");
    mPasswordEditText.setText("password");
}
```

I would like to export this value in a custom file that I would be able to put in my `.gitignore`.

I want to import variable from a file to my `build.gradle`.

```
debug {
    // import this 
    // { buildConfigField "String", "MOCK_EMAIL", "devtest@....com" }
    // { buildConfigField "String", "MOCK_PASSWORD", "password" }
    // from another file
}
```

Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save the variables inside `gradle.properties`

`mock_email=user@example.com`

and then inside your build.gradle add

`buildConfigField 'String', mock_email`

Another way could be to save them in environment variables say `MOCK_EMAIL` and then access them using `System.getenv('MOCK_EMAIL')`

Comment: But `gradle.properties` shouldn't be present in `.gitignore` right? Isn't possible to use `local.properties` or something else? I saw in `local.properties` file that properties can be erased by Android Studio.. :-/

Comment: It depends on you really, if you have defined any other properties there you cannot add it to `.gitignore` so in this case you are probably better off as defining these variables as environment variables. The project will still build without `gradle.properties` being present if that's your concern.